# Compiler not recognizing that class string value is equal to another String value

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, debugging, compare

```
public class Station {
    String name;
    boolean pass;
    int distance;

    // method to create a new Station taking the arguments of the name,pass and distance in the parameter
    public static Station createStation(String name, boolean pass, int distance) {  
    }

    // Array list containing all the Stations in London we will use
    static Station[] StationList = {createStation("Stepney Green", false, 100), createStation("Kings Cross", true, 700), createStation(
            "Oxford Circus", true, 200)};

    public static String infoAboutStation(Station station) {
        String message;
        if (station.pass)
            message = //string message
        else
            message = //string message
        return message;
    }

    public static String checkInfo(String stationName){
        String info = null;

        for(Station station : StationList){     
            if(stationName == station.name) { //it does not recognise it to be the same for some reason
                info = stationName + infoAboutStation(station);
            }
            else
                info = stationName + " message ";
        }
        return info;
    }

    public static void printInfo(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many... ");
        int totalResponses = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        String choice;
        for(int i = 0; i < totalResponses; ++i){
            System.out.println("Enter a station: ");
            choice = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(checkInfo(choice));
        }
    }
    // psvm(String[] args)
}
```

So the program runs fine but when we use "Stepney Green", "Kings Cross", "Oxford Circus" as the input for choice at `checkinfo(choice)`, it does not recognise it to be the same for `stationName == station.name` in the method `checkInfo(stationName //choice)`

Intellij debugger reads this at `stationName == station.name`

-StationList = {Station[3]@980} -> 0 = {Station@994} 1 = {Station@997} 2 = {Station@998}

-static -> StationList = {Station[3]@980}

-stationName = "Stepney Green" value = {byte[13]@996} coder = 0 hash = 0 hashisZero = 0

-info = null

-station = {Station@994}  -> name = "Stepney Green", pass = false, distance = 100

-station.name = "Stepney Green" -> value = {byte[13]@999] rest is zero

Beside the statement it says stationName: "Stepney Green" station: Station@994. Instead of printing out stationName + infoAboutStation it goes to the else station and prints "Stepney Green is not a London Underground Station". I am so puzzled as to why. Also if you don't mind helping me as to making this code a little more efficient and better.

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==` - that compares `stationName` and `station.name` reference the same string object. Since one is a compile time constant and the other a value read from a scanner they are **not** the same string object. Instead use `stationName.equals(station.Name)`

Comment: @ThomasKläger no, it only works with Oxford Circus now but not for the other two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare `String` using `equals()`
Replace this

```java
if(stationName == station.name)
```

by

```java
if(stationName.equals(station.name))
```

Comment: this does not work. It still gives the same error but this time it only works for "Oxford Circus" but not for "Kings Cross" and "Stepney Green"

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED** changed to

```
for(Station station : StationList){
    if(stationName.equals(station.name)) {
        info = stationName + infoAboutStation(station);
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help